# Finding partial string within horrible HTML using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Using Nokogiri, I want to fetch the part of the paragraph that comes after the `<span>` tags.

I am no regex hero, and it is the only thing that I need to discover before I can move forward. The only constant in the list is the `|` symbol, and the ugly way is to get the whole thing and `split` and `join` it I guess. Hopefully, there is a smarter, more elegant way!

```
<ul>
<li>
<p>
<strong>I don't care about </strong>
<span>|</span>
this I do care about
</p></li> ...
</ul>
```

Comment: What have you got so far? You probably want to look at the [`following-sibling` XPath axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes).

Comment: It's important to show us what you've written toward solving this. By doing that we can correct your code, rather than write something that doesn't fit and has to be shoehorned in, possibly inducing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HTML is that simple, then this will work:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<ul>
<li>
<p>
<strong>I don't care about </strong>
<span>|</span>
this I do care about
</p></li> ...
</ul>
EOT

doc.at('p').children.last # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ff1995c5b00 "\nthis I do care about\n">
doc.at('p').children.last.text # => "\nthis I do care about\n"
```

Parsing HTML and XML is really a matter of looking for landmarks that can be used to find what you want. In this case, `<span>` is OK, but getting the content you want based on that isn't quite as easy as looking up one level, to the `<p>` tag, grabbing its content, the `children`, selecting the last node in that list, which is text node containing the text you want.

The reason using the `<span>` tag is not the way I'd go is, if the HTML formatting changes, the number of nodes between `<span>` and your desired text could change. Intervening text nodes containing `"\n"` could be introduced for the formatting of the source, which would mess up a simple indexed lookup. To work around that, the code would have to ignore blank nodes and find the one that wasn't blank.

> I am no regex hero...

And you shouldn't try to be with HTML or XML. They're too flexible and can confound regular expressions unless you're dealing with extremely trivial searches on very static HTML, which isn't very likely in the real internet unless you're scanning abandoned pages. Instead, learn and rely on decent HTML/XML parsers, that can reduce a page into a DOM, making it easy to search and traverse the markup.

Comment: I knew there would be something elegant! And the HTML is indeed that simple. You're a life saver!